# Find original SOURCE attribute value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application where I'm taking a XAML template from a database record, plugging in new text strings and image references, and showing it in a window.

I take the XAML text and create a **DependencyObject** using this property:

```
public DependencyObject ParsedXamlTree
{
    get
    {
        String xaml;
        DependencyObject theDependencyObj;

        xaml = ProcessedXaml;
        byte[] xamlData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xaml);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xamlData))
        {
            theDependencyObj = (DependencyObject)XamlReader.Load(ms);
        }
        return theDependencyObj;
    }
}
```

Within the XAML will be an **Image** tag.  For example:

```
    <Image x:Name="categoryImage" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
           Height="240"  
           Margin="72,42,408,318"  
           VerticalAlignment="Center"  
           Width="320"  
           Source="SampleAssets\pacman-151558_640.png"/>
```

The problem I'm having is that when I parse the **DependencyObject** tree and get to the corresponding **Image** object, the string "SampleAssets\pacman-151558_640.png" from the **Source** attribute seems to be missing.

I notice that when it reads and parses the XAML, there is an IO exception being thrown within WPF itself.  That's the line where *XamlReader.Load* is called.  This exception is caught within the library so I'm only seeing evidence of it in the debug trace window.

I'm guessing that it's trying to find "SampleAssets\pacman-151558_640.png" for the **Image** tag and failing.  That's fine in itself, as I always figured the image sources would have to be patched up at runtime.

The question is, how do I retrieve the "SampleAssets\pacman-151558_640.png" string that was in the original XAML?  Is there somewhere in the **Image** object I can get this?

Worst case scenario would be parsing the XAML myself to find the tag and extracting the attribute string from it, but I'm hoping that's not necessary.

Comment: Providing the Image with a valid Source is exactly the goal here. But doing that requires getting the original attribute string so that (for example) an assets folder path can be added. That part of the path isn't in the XAML because it could be different from one system to another.  I understand that the Source is an ImageSource and not a string, but i was hoping there is some easy way of retrieving the original attribute.

Comment: Well, I ended up just parsing the XAML code myself.  Wasn't quite as painful as I'd expected, fortunately.

Answer (score 1):

WPF has a built-in type converter ([`ImageSourceConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter.aspx)) that converts URI strings to `ImageSource` objects (the type of the `Image.Source` property). If an image could not be loaded from an URI string, the converter returns null, so the `Source` property of your Image control will also be null.

There is nothing in the object tree that will keep the URI of a non-available image. You will have to parse the XAML Template before loading and replace invalid image URIs by valid ones.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the type converter and never expected the Image.Source property to be populated by the XamlReader. I was just hoping there was some way to get at the original attribute string so I could avoid parsing the XAML myself.